KeyError raised at input layer when trying to build a model with 2 inputs
KeyError: "Exception encountered when calling Functional.call().\n\n\x1b[1m140112707155856\x1b[0m\n\nArguments 
received by Functional.call():
\n  • inputs={'input_1': 'tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 256, 256, 3), dtype=float32)', 
'input_2': 
'tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 256, 256, 3), dtype=float32)'}\n  
• training=True\n  • mask={'input_1': 'None', 'input_2': 'None'}"

This error raised when train the model.
There is also a
UserWarning: The structure of `inputs` doesn't match the expected structure: 
['input_1', 'input_2']. Received: the structure of inputs={'input_1': '*', 'input_2': '*'}

when make SNN class return inputs=[input_1, input_2], instead of inputs={"input_1": input_1, "input_2": input_2}.
Read dataset from json file like:
[
    {
        "img1": "./river/river_050.jpg",
        "img2": "./airplane/airplane_111.jpg",
        "label1": 32,
        "label2": 0,
        "pair_label": 0
    },
    {
        "img1": "./railway_station/railway_station_043.jpg",
        "img2": "./airplane/airplane_146.jpg",
        "label1": 30,
        "label2": 0,
        "pair_label": 0
    },
......

One of the base model:
class AttentionBlock(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, filters, **kwargs):
        super(AttentionBlock, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.global_avg_pool = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
        self.dense1 = layers.Dense(filters // 8, activation="relu")
        self.dense2 = layers.Dense(filters, activation="sigmoid")
        self.multiply = layers.Multiply()

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.global_avg_pool(inputs)
        x = self.dense1(x)
        x = self.dense2(x)
        x = self.multiply([inputs, tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(x, axis=1), axis=2)])
        return x


class BaseModelCNN:
    def __init__(self, input_shape=(256, 256, 3), num_classes=45):
        
        self.input_shape = input_shape
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        self.model = self.build_model()

    def build_model(self):
        
        inputs = layers.Input(shape=self.input_shape, dtype="float32", name="input_CNN")

        
        base_model = ResNet152V2(include_top=False, weights="imagenet", input_shape=self.input_shape)
        num_layers = len(base_model.layers)
        active_count = int(0.3 * num_layers)

        
        for i, layer in enumerate(base_model.layers):
            layer.trainable = i < active_count or i == num_layers - 1

        x = base_model(inputs)

        x = AttentionBlock(filters=base_model.output_shape[-1])(x)

        x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
        x = layers.Dropout(0.05)(x)
        outputs = layers.Dense(self.num_classes, activation="softmax", name='output_a')(x)

        return models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

Another one:
class BaseModelViT:
    def __init__(self, input_shape=(256, 256, 3), num_classes=45):

        self.input_shape = input_shape
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        self.model = self.build_model()

    def build_model(self):
        
        inputs = layers.Input(shape=self.input_shape, dtype="float32", name="input_ViT")

        swin_base = SwinTransformerV2Tiny256(include_top=False)

        x = swin_base(inputs)

        
        x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
        x = layers.Dropout(0.1)(x)
        outputs = layers.Dense(self.num_classes, activation="softmax", name='output_b')(x)

        return models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

Build model:
class SNNModel:
    def __init__(self, input_shape=(256, 256, 3), num_classes=45):

        self.input_shape = input_shape
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        self.cnn_model = BaseModelCNN(input_shape, num_classes)
        self.vit_model = BaseModelViT(input_shape, num_classes)
        self.model = self.build_model()

    def build_model(self):
        
        input_1 = layers.Input(shape=self.input_shape, name="input_1")
        input_2 = layers.Input(shape=self.input_shape, name="input_2")

        cnn_output = self.cnn_model.model(input_1)
        vit_output = self.vit_model.model(input_2)


        cnn_intermediate = self.cnn_model.model.layers[-2].output # Shape: (None, 2048)
        vit_intermediate = self.vit_model.model.layers[-2].output # Shape: (None, 768)
        

        projection_dim = 768
        
        cnn_projected = layers.Dense(projection_dim, activation="relu", name="cnn_projected")(cnn_intermediate)
        cnn_projected = layers.BatchNormalization(name="cnn_projected_bn")(cnn_projected)
        cnn_projected = layers.Dropout(0.3, name="cnn_projected_dropout")(cnn_projected)

        vit_projected = layers.Dense(projection_dim, activation="relu", name="vit_projected")(vit_intermediate)
        vit_projected = layers.BatchNormalization(name="vit_projected_bn")(vit_projected)
        vit_projected = layers.Dropout(0.3, name="vit_projected_dropout")(vit_projected)


        distance = layers.Lambda(
            lambda tensors: K.sqrt(K.sum(K.square(tensors[0] - tensors[1]), axis=1, keepdims=True)),
            output_shape=(1,),
            name="distance"
        )([cnn_projected, vit_projected])

        return models.Model(
            inputs={"input_1": input_1, "input_2": input_2},
            outputs={"output_a": cnn_output, "output_b": vit_output, "distance": distance},
        )

    def compile(self):

        def contrastive_loss(self, y_true, y_pred):
            margin = 1.0
            positive_loss = y_true * K.square(y_pred)
            negative_loss = (1 - y_true) * K.square(K.maximum(margin - y_pred, 0))
            return K.mean(positive_loss + negative_loss)
            

        optimizer = self.get_optimizer_admw()

        self.model.compile(
            optimizer=optimizer,
            loss={
                "output_a": CategoricalCrossentropy(),
                "output_b": CategoricalCrossentropy(),
                "distance": contrastive_loss,
            },
            loss_weights={
                "output_a": 1.0,
                "output_b": 1.0,
                "distance": 0.5,
            },
            metrics={
                "output_a": "accuracy",
                "output_b": "accuracy",
                "distance": None,
            },
        )
    
    def get_optimizer_admw(self, learning_rate=1e-4):
        lr_schedule = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
            initial_learning_rate=learning_rate,
            decay_steps=10000,
            decay_rate=0.96,
            staircase=True
        )
        return AdamW(learning_rate=lr_schedule, amsgrad=True)

Train:
model = model_class(input_shape=INPUT_SHAPE, num_classes=NUM_CLASSES)
model.compile()

def preprocess_image(img_path):
    img = load_img(img_path, target_size=INPUT_SHAPE[:2])  # Resizing
    img_array = img_to_array(img)
    img_array = img_array / 255.0  # Normalize to [0, 1]
    return img_array    

def data_generator(data_file, batch_size, is_training=True):
    with open(data_file, 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    
    while True:
        # Shuffle data for training
        if is_training:
            np.random.shuffle(data)
        
        for i in range(0, len(data), batch_size):
            batch = data[i:i + batch_size]
            img1_batch = []
            img2_batch = []
            label1_batch = []
            label2_batch = []
            pair_label_batch = []
            
            for entry in batch:
                img1 = preprocess_image(entry["img1"])
                img2 = preprocess_image(entry["img2"])
                
                img1_batch.append(img1)
                img2_batch.append(img2)
                label1_batch.append(entry["label1"])
                label2_batch.append(entry["label2"])
                pair_label_batch.append(entry["pair_label"])
            
            img1_batch = np.array(img1_batch, dtype=np.float32)
            img2_batch = np.array(img2_batch, dtype=np.float32)
            label1_batch = to_categorical(label1_batch, num_classes=NUM_CLASSES)
            label2_batch = to_categorical(label2_batch, num_classes=NUM_CLASSES)
            pair_label_batch = np.array(pair_label_batch, dtype=np.int32)
            
            yield (
                {"input_1": img1_batch, "input_2": img2_batch},  
                {"output_a": label1_batch, "output_b": label2_batch, "distance": pair_label_batch} 
            )

def get_dataset(data_file, batch_size, is_training=True):
    return tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        lambda: data_generator(data_file, batch_size, is_training),
        output_signature=(
            {
                "input_1": tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, *INPUT_SHAPE), dtype=tf.float32),  # img1
                "input_2": tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, *INPUT_SHAPE), dtype=tf.float32)   # img2
            },
            {
                "output_a": tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, NUM_CLASSES), dtype=tf.float32),  # label1
                "output_b": tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, NUM_CLASSES), dtype=tf.float32),  # label2
                "distance": tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32)                 # pair_label
            }
        )
    ).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

def train_model(model, train_data_file=TRAIN_DATA_FILE, val_data_file=VAL_DATA_FILE, epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE):
    train_dataset = get_dataset(train_data_file, batch_size, is_training=True)
    val_dataset = get_dataset(val_data_file, batch_size, is_training=False)
    
    print("train model")
    
    history = model.fit(
        train_dataset,
        epochs=epochs,
        validation_data=val_dataset,
        callbacks=[
            tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
                filepath=os.path.join(MODEL_SAVE_PATH, MODEL_FILE_NAME),
                save_weights_only=False,
                save_best_only=True
            )
        ],
    )

This error keeps occurring as I try different types of input.
It also exists when using output_types and output_shapes .

Please post a [mre].
